# Using Html.BeginForm and Semantic UI

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, semantic-ui

When I use `Html.BeginForm`, the semantic UI will runs off and uses the classic UI.

How do I get this fixed?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<div id="addRestaurant">
    <form class="ui form">
        <div class="required field">
            <label for="resName">Restaurant Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="model.RestaurantName" id="RestaurantName"/>
        </div>
...
</div>
}
```

**Before using Html.BeginForm**
[image]

**After using Html.BeginForm**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the class to the mvc form

```
<div id="addRestaurant">
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName","ControllerName", method: FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { @class="ui form"} )) {

        <div class="required field">
            <label for="resName">Restaurant Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="model.RestaurantName" id="RestaurantName"/>
        </div>
...

}
</div>
```